# Updating value of class derived from float

Tags: python

Following up on [Python values with units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852720/python-values-with-units), if I have a class derived from float like this:

```
class float_with_units(float):
    def __new__(self,value,units):
        return float.__new__(self,value)

    def __init__(self,value,units):
        self.units = units

    def setval(self,newval):
        self = float_with_units(newval,self.units)

T = float_with_units(100,'C')
T.setval(200)
print T,T.units
```

the value won't update.  This returns "100.0 C" when I would expect it to return "200.0 C".

Why doesn't this work and what should I be doing instead?

EDIT- The two answers suggesting adding a __str__ method certainly solve the problem, but it turns out not quite the one I was intending to ask.  The float format has value for me as more than just a string- I'd like to be able to math with the floats which I can't do with strings.  For example I'd like to do operations like this:

```
T = float_with_units(100,'C')
T2 = T+T
```

which works fine with the original value but I can't edit it and then perform more operations.

The obvious solution is to just use T.value explicitly but having all those .value's hanging around my code makes it very hard to read.

Comment: Reassigning `self` in `setval` only changes what that local variable points to. It doesn't have any impact on the value of `T`.

Comment: Why do you want to update an immutable type in-place?(Immutable objects always return a new object when an operation is performed on them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immutable (sub)classes in Python can't have methods like the`setval()`in your question. Instead you'll need to do something along these lines:

```
class FloatWithUnits(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, units):
        inst = super(FloatWithUnits, cls).__new__(cls, value)
        inst.units = units
        return inst

    def withval(self, newval):
        return FloatWithUnits(newval, self.units)

T = FloatWithUnits(100, 'C')
T = T.withval(200)
print T, T.units  # 200.0 C
```

The advantage of subclassing immutable types is that you can use them anywhere their base class could have been, which is often useful when interfacing with other code that can't be changed to accept a new type, like most existing third-party modules.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```
class float_with_units(float):
    def __new__(self,value,units):
        return float.__new__(self,value)

    def __init__(self,value,units):
        self._units = units
        self._value = value

    def setval(self,value):
        self._value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return '%f %s' % (self._value, self._units)            

T = float_with_units(100,'C')
T.setval(200)
print T
```

produces: `200.000000 C`